# How to Demonstrate that 68%, 95%, and 99.7% of the values in s are indeed within 1, 2, and 3 standard distributions of the mean?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statistics

I have a pandas series `s` where the data follows a normal distribution.

I have 100 numbers in this series. I want to demonstrate that 68%, 95%, and 99.7% of the values in s are indeed within 1, 2, and 3 standard distributions of the mean.

I do like that:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

s = Series(np.random.normal(0, 100, 100))
```

To demonstrate that 68% of the values in `s` are indeed within 1 standard distributions of the mean I do like that:

```
s1 = s[s>= (s.mean() - s.std())].count()
s2 = s[s<= (s.mean() + s.std())].count()

percentage = (s1 +  s2)/s.count()
```

I get `1.68463` as the value in `percentage`.

My question:
1- Is the my way correct to compute the 1 standard deviation.
2- Why I get 1.68463. Following the empirical rule I must get 68.463, no?
3- Is there other better way to compute the percentage

Comment: You are dubble counting. This would be correct `s[(s.mean() - s.std() <  s) & (s < (s.mean() + s.std()))].count() / s.count()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
np.random.seed(0)

# generate a large number of points
s = Series(np.random.normal(0, 100, 100_000))

# compute mean and std
mean = s.mean()
std = s.std()

# normalize the data (x-mean)/std
normalized = s.sub(mean).abs().div(std)

# count the proportion of values for each step
# [0, 1], (1, 2], (2, 3], (3, np.inf]
# and compute the cumulative proportion
out = (
 pd.cut(normalized, bins=[0, 1, 2, 3, np.inf],
        labels=['≤1', '≤2', '≤3', '>3']
       )
   .value_counts(normalize=True)
   .cumsum()
)
```

Output:

```
≤1    0.68463
≤2    0.95382
≤3    0.99714
>3    1.00000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Your filters are wrong. You need to filter out  the numbers **between** the mean and standard deviation. Not just the numbers less than or grater than.

```
s1 = s[(s.mean() >= s) & (s >= (s.mean() - s.std()))].count()
s2 = s[(s.mean() <= s) & (s<= (s.mean() + s.std()))].count()
```